# Error connecting to ec2 instance with third party api

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am using a third party api which accepts json input and response back with a json format output. Locally I checked the api response on port 8181 and it works great. When I am deploying and testing the same on production environment over AWS, its failing with error :

Could not get any response
There seems to be an error connecting to https://ec2 instance public ip:8181/auth/raw

I am able to ping the public ip of the server. I have already tried exploring the solution but could not find any.
Please suggest how can i resolve this.

Comment: did you open the port on the fiewall?

Comment: i can not as its listening http over port 80 already

Comment: I see you are using HTTPS and EC2-XX-XX-XX endpoint / IP address. Does not seem right unless you are using self signed certificate and SSL running on port 8181 ?

Answer (score 2):

I got to solve it myself after breaking my head like anything by adding Custom TCP Rule on port 8181 over Inbound under security group of the instance.